# Indicate "freshness" of featured Meta posts in the Bulletin

Tags: feature-request, community-bulletin, featured-tag

Community Bulleting and `featured`-tag together are a decent way to promote important things on Meta to more users. However, I feel¹ like the following frequently happens:

1. Users sees new featured question, clicks through.
2. User reads, interacts, and clicks away.
3. The user ignores the Bulletin entry of this question in the future: "been there".
4. The user misses new answers (among other things).

I propose that the Bulletin indicate that there is new stuff to see. There are two options: indicate "new stuff since you last visited" or print "updated [date-time]". The latter is more in line with how SE works in other places, so that's probably the way it should be.

Mockup:

[image]

---

1. Voting and commenting patterns, but I have not collected proof.

Comment: Another option could be to include the number of answers: "Inspirations towards a logo for cs.SE (14 answers)" - wouldn't involve user-specific data ("been there") and would still convey "freshness" ("was 2 answers when I last saw it")

Comment: @Mat'sMug True. Doesn't show edits, though.